# About elongation produced in a body, when 2 forces of equal magnitude but opp. in direction are applied on a body

Tags: material-science, elasticity

When 2 oppositely- directed forces are applied on the same body , they act at the body's center of mass(com). The vector sum of the forces thus becomes 0(zero). How do the forces then bring about deformation(elongation or de-elongation) in the body?

Comment: The forces do not have to act on the center of mass of the body. For the purpose of treating the motion of the body in the particle approximation (i.e. neglecting rotation and deformation) we treat them as if they would attach to the center of mass, but that's an approximation that is not valid when the forces attach anywhere else. The resulting math, however, is a lot more difficult than the particle approximation, which is why we don't teach it until approx. 3rd or 4th semester of a four years physics program.

Comment: can u pl. elucidate. I didn't get ur pt.I am actually a class 11 student from India.

Comment: When you are interested in deformations, like e.g. the mechanical engineers have to be, you need continuum mechanics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics. To be very honest with you, I found it to be one of the more excruciating classes that I got the least out of. That doesn't mean it isn't important, it's just tough as nails and unsatisfactory in the sense that most non-trivial problems require heavy duty numerics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CuriousOne said, the forces may be said to "exactly cancel" and be neglected only if they act on the same part of the body, i.e. if both of them act on the center of mass (or on the whole object "uniformly").

[image]

That's not the case when the object is deformed. The simplest example is to imagine that the object is a pair of cubes connected with a spring. Imagine that the force $F$ points in the opposite direction than on the picture, please. At any rate, you may imagine that the left-pointing force acts on the left box while the right-pointing force acts on the right box.

By the principle of action and reaction (or incompressibility of the boxes), the boxes act on the spring with the same outward-directed forces, and that's why the spring stretches. The deformation of any object is different in detail but mathematically analogous to the stretching or compression of a spring.

Comment: Ur explanation redresses my doubt totally . Thanks a lot.